# What is the difference between % and * wildcards in Make?

Tags: makefile

I'm currently learning Make and am struggling to wrap my head around the wildcard concept. Specifically, it seems like there are two symbols that can represent wildcards: * and %

For example, say I want to to generate a variable that identifies all .c source files in the working directory. I would use the traditional * symbol in *.c However, if I use the patsubst function, I am required to use the % symbol instead of * symbol:

```
// WORKS 
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)               # list of source files
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRC)) # list of object files

// DOES NOT WORK!!!!
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)               # list of source files
OBJS = $(patsubst *.c, *.o, $(SRC)) # list of object files
```

Can someone explain the difference between * and % in the context of Make wildcards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain the difference between * and % in the context of Make wildcards?

### TL;DR:

- This is all specific to GNU `make`.
- `*` and a few other characters are special to the `wildcard` function, but not to `patsubst`.  This kind of pattern is *expanded* to the names of existing files and directories that match the pattern, possibly more than one for each pattern.
- `%` is special to the `patsubst` function.  This kind of pattern is used to *select* matching strings provided by the makefile or directly by `make`, in the process capturing the part matching the `%` for later use.
- Both kinds have application to the target and prerequisite lists of rules, but their significance there is somewhat different from each other.
- None of these are significant to `make` in recipes, but `wildcard`-style patterns are significant to the shell, and the shell will interpret them in recipes that it executes.

### General

Understand first that `$(wildcard)` and `$(patsubst)` are features specific to *GNU's implementation* of `make`, and GNU `make` also attributes special significance to `%`, `*`, and a few other characters in rule targets and prerequisites.  The POSIX specifications for `make` say nothing about any of that.  GNU `make` is widely used these days, and with good reason, but it is not the only `make` you might encounter.  If you want maximum portability among `make` implementations then you must avoid these altogether.

Understand also that a complete, albeit rather basic response to the question would be simply "yes, the `wildcard` and `patsubst` functions recognize different special characters."  These functions do different things, so it is potentially useful that the special characters of one can be used as ordinary characters in the other.

### Wildcards

The asterisk (`*`) is among the special characters recognized by the Bourne shell for "pathname expansion", which replaces patterns with the names of possibly-many **existing** files and directories matching the pattern.  There are more characters than just `*` significant in pathname expansion, but `%` is not among them. Look up that term for a full description.

Additionally, there is the tilde (`~`), which `make` and some shells recognize for "tilde expansion", which involves interpreting the first segments of affected paths as specified users' home directories.

The GNU `make` documentation describes the characters and constructs it recognizes for pathname and tilde expansion as "wildcards", and it has this to say about them:

> Wildcard expansion is performed by `make` automatically in targets and in prerequisites. In recipes, the shell is responsible for wildcard expansion. In other contexts, wildcard expansion happens only if you request it explicitly with the `wildcard` function.

([GNU make manual, section 4.4](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html#Wildcards))

And that's where the `wildcard` function appearing in the question comes in -- if you want to perform the same wildcard expansion that `make` performs automatically on target and prerequisite names in some other context, such as a variable definition, then you can use [the `wildcard` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html#Wildcard-Function) to get it.  Thus,

> ```
> SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
> ```

results variable `SRC` representing a list of all the existing files in the working directory at the time the makefile is parsed whose names end with `.c`.

On the other hand, `%` is not significant for pathname or tilde expansion, so

```
SRC = $(wildcard %.c)
```

will expand to literally `%.c`.

### Patterns

The shell documentation uses the term "pattern" to mean shell input that is interpreted to be subject to pathname expansion, rather than being literal.  However, GNU `make` reserves the term for a different kind of pattern in which the `%` character features.  This is relevant in two main areas: [the `patsubst` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions) and [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#index-pattern-rule).

#### The `patsubst` function

The `patsubst` function computes one string or series of strings from another by replacing those that match a given pattern with a specified replacement.  In a pattern, the first `%` character, if any, matches any number of characters, including zero.  In this sense, it can be described as a wildcard, and the manual does, somewhat confusingly, use that term.  If the replacement also contains at least one `%` then the first is replaced by the substring that was matched by the `%` in the pattern.

Note well that this has nothing inherently to do with file names, existing or otherwise.

Thus, with

```
SRC = main.c other.c
OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
```

the `%.c` pattern matches first `main.c` (with `%` matching `main`) and then `other.c` (with `%` matching `other`), and the result for `OBJ` is the same as this:

```
OBJ = main.o other.o
```

regardless of whether any files named `main.c`, `other.c`, `main.o`, or `other.o` exist.

#### Pattern rules

If the target of a rule contains a `%`, then it is interpreted by GNU `make` as a pattern rule.  Pattern rules use `%` in much the same way that `patsubst` does.  When `make` needs to build a target but does not have a rule for that specific target, it will check whether the target name matches the target pattern of any pattern rule (including some built-in ones).  There does not need to be any existing file of that name.  If it finds a match, then it will use that rule to build the target.  And in that case, for the purpose of building the target in question, the first `%` character, if any, in any prerequisite names specified in that rule will be replaced by the stem that matched the `%` in the target, much like in `patsubst`.

### Combinations

Usually, only one of these kinds of pattern matching / expansion is desired in any given context, but sometimes they can usefully be combined.  For example, consider this pattern rule:

```
%.o: %.c *.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

That says that any `.o` file can be built from a corresponding `.c` file and *all* the `.h` files in the working directory by applying the provided recipe.

Answer (score 0):

The `wildcard` function expects wildcard characters  (`~`, `*`, `?` and `[...]` which match on file names) while the `patsubst` function expects a pattern (`%`) that operates on text.  As such `$(patsubst *.c, *.o, $(SRC))` means replace the literal string `*.c` with the string `*.o` and `SRC` probably does not contain any literal `*.c` strings.